# Why doesn't the AdditionalLibPaths parameter work in this MSBuild command?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, msbuild, compilation

I am trying to specify an additional folder to look for references when doing a command-line compile with MSBuild.

```
cmd> msbuild LurReports.sln /t:Rebuild /p:AdditionalLibPaths=C:\Radio;TargetFrameworkVersion=v2.0
```

For whatever reasons, msbuild completely ignores the `C:\Radio` folder when looking for references.  What am I missing here?

- This box does not have Visual Studio installed
- The .sln is VS2008 and I am compiling it against.NET 2.0.
- I also tried double quotes around the path.

Comment: Did you try putting double quotes around the entire property value, and then escaping it?

/p:AdditionalLibPaths="C:\\Radio;TargetFrameworkVersion=v2.0"

Comment: Do you get an exception or error message? Can you please add `/v:diagnostic` to your command and print anything relevant here.

Comment: @AngryHacker: You can put AdditionalProperties in your itemgroup and mentioning ReferencePath="" . It will solve the issue

Comment: @AngryHacker Is this resolved? I'm running into the same issue and couldn't find a right solution on this problem.